# Barcode Scanner (ZXing) crashing

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing

First off i want to tell you i have done all i can. Followed like 10 tutorials on internet and 10 threads on stacked. Still no success.

I know guys that you recommend using scanning via intent,but in my case its not an option and i need to have it native in my app.

I have downloaded the zxing library (2.1) and followed [this tutorial](http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/)

When i run this code on my Galaxy S3 or Galaxy Tab 10.1 as debug, the program crashes, after freezing for like 20 seconds, when i click the button that should start intent for result: `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` or `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity`.

Note that i have copied all the resources from Barcode Scanner app like beep sound, xml files and other.

[Crash Log](http://pastebin.com/CvuusVbc)

My code is below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.philipscan;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void scanNow(View view)
    {
        Log.e("test", "button works!");

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
    } 

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.e("xZing", "Back");
        if (requestCode == 3) 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.e("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);
                // Handle successful scan
            } 
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel
                Log.e("xZing", "Cancelled");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.philipscan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.philipscan.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My SRC folder**

[image: My file list]

I'm very thankful for all the help i can get.

Comment: Crash log: http://pastebin.com/CvuusVbc

Comment: your crash shows that com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity  is not found cross check for this activity in you code

Answer (score 1):

Try to create `Intent` another way

```
Intent scanIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
scanIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
```

then startActivityForResult() as usual. ONE_D_MODE is mode to scan 1D barcodes like Code39.

Comment: try to put extras as shown in answer upgrade. No detail information about exception in log :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove all this code you copied from our project. It's not necessary, you're not understanding it, and it's not supposed to be reused this way under the license: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions

In particular you are not supposed to copy the manifest, and not allowed to copy the UI.

Instead, it is much simpler, since you seem to be trying to use Intents anyway: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent